# Why windows administrative shares enabled automatically after a few hours even after I delete it?

Tags: windows-10

To enhance the security of Windows OS, I've removed administrative shares with the following command.

```
net share C$ /delete
net share Z$ /delete
```

Then I verify it again with `net share` command to make sure it's not there.

```
C:\>net share
There are no entries in the list.

C:\>
```

After a few hours, the default shares came back

```
C:\> net share

Share name   Resource                        Remark

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Z$           Z:\                             Default share
C$           C:\                             Default share
The command completed successfully.


C:\>
```

Is there any idea why this happen?

Is this a standard behavior on Windows?

Comment: Is the computer part of a domain? If so, the group policies push them back.

Comment: Thanks @LPChip, is there any log for this? Event viewer? I would like to identify the exact time when this happen.

Comment: Every 90 minutes, Group Policy will refresh on your system. The exact time is not precisely 90 minutes, because this refresh is spread out to be less of a burdon on the server. Whenever Group Policy refreshes, this is registered in the Event Log.

Answer (score 3):

This is auto feature.

To disable it with registry:

Please create a Dword value in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
named AutoShareWks, give it 0 value.

[image]

Comment: Correct, after that you need to restart the "Server" service or to reboot the PC

Comment: Thanks @Karen Hu. I don't see this problem on Windows 7 (it won't be enabled back after I delete it). Only in Windows 10